# Angular two way binding radio inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two sets of radio inputs:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" ng-model="domestic" ng-checked="domestic"> Domestic
<input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="international" ng-checked="international"> International
```

and:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" ng-model="domestic" ng-checked="domestic"> Verified
<input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="international" ng-checked="international"> Unverified
```

Regardless of which input in either set I click I want it to change the same one in the other set accordingly.

I have written it like this because I want it to work both ways.

Is this the right way to bind? or is there a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think about it from an abstracted standpoint. What you're doing now is binding two radio inputs to the same value. If you want both radio inputs to represent the same data value in all cases, what you're doing is fine.

Otherwise you can always set `ng-checked` to a function. This would be ideal if you had other considerations you wanted to make. Something like:

```
<input type="radio" value="0" ng-model="domestic" ng-checked="domesticChecked()"> Domestic
```

Using:

```
$scope.domesticChecked = function(){
    // you could do other checks here as well if it needed to be more complicated
   return (domestic && someOtherConsideration) ? true : false
 }
```

In short, if all scenarios in your app present a 1:1 value association between those two checkboxes (if one is checked, the other is **always** checked too and vice versa) then what you have is fine.

Comment: great thanks for that. in some aspects there is a lot of information on angular best practice and in other aspects hardly anything. thanks for the fast reply. I'll take into account the function method as I might need to consider things as my elements are very connected.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
<input type="radio" value="0" ng-model="domestic" name="x"> Domestic
<input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="domestic" name="x"> International


<input type="radio" value="0" ng-model="domestic" name="y"> Verified
<input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="domestic" name="y"> Unverified
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xehkr3ks/)

You need to assign names to the radio elements so that they can be grouped, then if you use the same `ng-model` you should be fine.